# Visual Code Removes whitespace from within function parentheses

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, code-formatting

I'm finding that the most recent Visual code build 1.26.1 (on Windows 10) is removing spaces from within C++ function parentheses when I add a ; at the end of the line. How can I stop this without turning off formatting completely?

An example

```
void this_is_a_test( Parameter_type &parameter )
```

becomes

```
void this_is_a_test(Parameter_type &parameter);
```

This seems a minor thing to complain/ask about but these spaces are required by the coding standards for the company I'm working at so is a severe pain in the proverbial.

Comment: @bolov there are several C++ extensions available

Answer (score 2):

The VSCode beautifier is [`clang-format`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp#_editing-code), and the [clang-format option](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html)  you're looking for is `SpacesInParentheses = true`.